# SAL Annotations will trigger compiler to report error?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sal

I am learning SAL Annotations, I tested this example in Visual Studio 2017.

I thought the compiler will report warning or error when I pass a NULL pointer to `InCallee`, however, it still can build correctly.so my question is whether SAL is just like code comments and won't validate legality of the data, or it can check the data, just because I made something wrong?

```
void InCallee(_In_ int *pInt) //_In_ is allowed to be NULL 
{
   int i = *pInt;
}

void GoodInCaller()
{
   int *pInt = new int;
   *pInt = 5;

   InCallee(pInt);
   delete pInt;
}

void BadInCaller()
{
   int *pInt = NULL;
   InCallee(pInt); // pInt should not be NULL
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=vs-2015#using-the-visual-studio-code-analysis-tool-to-find-defects

Comment: The **compiler** doesn't validate SAL annotations, they are just a bunch of empty preprocessor `#define`s as far as the C and C++ languages are concerned. SAL annotations are used by **static analysis tools** instead.

Comment: where can I get the **static analysis tools** ？